# Int in list with String is AnyObject?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

What is wrong with this code?

How can I specify the list to be Strings and Numbers?

I am getting an error 'AnyObject is not convertible to 'Int'

```
var stringNum = ["name", 2]

var number:Int = stringNum[1]
```

Comment: Swift tries to help you by providing type safety. Usually, you don't need to have an array that contains objects of multiple types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are confident that elements in your array are typed as you expect then simply

```
 var number:Int = stringNum[1] as Int
```

works.  But, if you are unsure about the type consistency in your array elements then you'll need to confirm the types before assigning.

Comment: The array in the OP's code contains both a String and an Int as contents.

Comment: He knows element `[1]` is an `Int` - he just can't get the compiler to agree with him.  [This answer does not deserve a down vote from you.]

Comment: If he only needed two constants, he wouldn't use an array. Additionally, the other answer is a good example of confirming the type.

Comment: Like he is not parsing JSON or properties files when he has a subarray of `[ ... ["stringy" inty] ...]`

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for. var number = stringNum[1] as Int

Comment: @masters3d just keep in mind that you will get a runtime error if stringNum[1] is not an Int. If you are not worried about that, then this is certainly a shorter and still valid way to do the conversion

Answer (score 2):

The array is inferred to be of the type `[AnyObject]` and in swift, you must always explicitly [downcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) your variables.

You need to test if the value can be converted to an Int:

```
if let number : Int = stringNum[1] as? Int {
    // use number as Int
}
```

The `as?` operator will return `nil` if the value cannot be converted and the `if` block will not be run, otherwise it will return the value converted to Int and run the `if` block with `number` set to the Int value